# Recursive function that prints the letters of the alphabet one per line, one per function call

Tags: python, recursion

Well, I am still learning python and trying to print letters of alphabet one per line, one per function call. This should be done using recursion.

Here I am struggling due to error. Just need another pair of eyes to see if there is something missing.

```
def recursive_print(cursor):
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz'
index = len(alphabet) - cursor
if index > 0
 recursive_print(index - 1)
 letter = alphabet[index]   
print letter

print recursive_print(0)
```

Error below:

```
NameError: name 'index' is not defined                                                                                                                                                                
sh-4.3$ python main.py                                                                                                                                                                                
File "main.py", line 4                                                                                                                                                                              
if index > 0:                                                                                                                                                                                     
^
```

Any Pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: This looks like and infinite recursion for me... have you tried calling `recursive_print(curser + 1)`? Also, your first index is going to be out of range, it needs to be smaller than `len(alphabet)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem, you haven't indented properly.  You're also missing a colon on the **if** statement you posted.  Try this:

```
def recursive_print(curser):
  alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz'
  index = len(alphabet) - curser
  if index > 0:
    recursive_print(index - 1)

  letter = alphabet[index]
  print letter

print recursive_print(0)
```

Next, you have to worry about is the infinite recursion from not handling your index properly.  I believe that the problem is a trivial mental error: change the recursion to

```
recursive_print(curser + 1)
```

This still gives you an index out of range on the base case, but I expect you can fix that.

BTW, the word is spelled "cursor", in case you care.

Comment: Thanks @prune. I will check the suggestion and will post the working code. This definitely helped.